How to insert keyframe in Blender?
How to insert keyframe in like this? I don't know how to do this.


What kind of keyframes? The shortcut is i to keyframe with the default settings, k yo choose what kind of keyframe, Shift K to choose the default keyframe that will be created with i

To add a single keyframe, go to the frame you want, position the object properly and press I (full keyframe, location, rotation and scale) or K (custom keyframe)
Now, your image shows one keyframe for every frame, which is probably the result of a script or a baking.
If you have created a "simulation", you can search around how to "bake the simulation".
If you know how to script (python), then you can create your script to add keyframes for all frames.
But in regular animations, people only set a few keyframes manually and adjust the interpolations in the "Graph Editor".
Unfortunately it's not possible to answer your question better than that as it contains no other information.
